# overflow breaks javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use a javascript to change a div when you past a certain height scrolling:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scroll > 300){
            $('#div').addClass('class');
        }
        if(scroll > 500){
            $('#div').removeClass('class');
        }

    });
```

But on the CSS, the properties:

```
body, html{
    overflow-x: hidden
}
```

makes the Javascript useless, and it's both X and Y, i've tried with only one hidden, unset, etc. And they need to be BOTH unset for this script to work.

I would like any way to go around this, either a new Javascript function or any other way to hide the scroll bars. Thank you :)

Tried: CSS overflow:hidden + Javascript scrollTop Expected: work Result: didn't work

Comment: In a comment you said you are actually trying to use overflow: overlay.  Yet, "overlay" is depreciated and is no different from using the default "auto".

Comment: I tried overflow: auto, it gives me a different bar than overflow: overlay.
Auto gives me a totally white bar
Overlay gives me an invisible bar with the white thumb (what I want)

(I'm not using the normal css bar and thumb)

Comment: I think your best option is to use auto and then hide the scrollbar.  See this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/64vpqd50/show).